# Phonegap / Cordova: Storing password securely?

Tags: security, encryption, cordova

I'm developing a Cordova app (at this moment just for iOS) and I need to store the user's password that is used to call some web services to retrieve data.

I've been searching information about this, for example in this [Google code thread](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/8786e0c4ce9107db) the last answer says that storing the password unencrypted on my phonegap localstorage is secure enough...:

Then, in the Phonegap wiki they talk about native methods for iOS, but it looks like they have been cracked already, and I don't like this solution because it makes my app code platform dependent.

Can you help me please?

Comment: So what did you end up with finally? It would be great if you share your solution here for others.

Answer (score 0):

The Keychain Plugin is probably your best bet.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Keychain

Comment: It seems this project doesn't exist anymore